# Javascript call prototype methods

Tags: class, methods, prototype, phaser-framework

```
var newGame = {};
newGame.Game.prototype =  {
prepareToJump: function() {
if (ninja.body.velocity.y == 0) {
  powerBar = game.add.sprite(ninja.x, ninja.y - 50, "powerbar");
  powerBar.width = 0;
  powerTween = game.add.tween(powerBar).to({
    width: 100
  }, 1000, "Linear", true);
  game.input.onDown.remove(newGame.Game.prototype.prepareToJump, this);
  game.input.onUp.add(newGame.Game.prototype.jump, this);
}

},
jump: function() {
this.prepareToJump(); // undefinded
//but we can use newGame.Game.prototype.prepareToJump();
}
}
```

Why can't I use `this.prepareToJump()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont use it like

```
this.prepareToJump()
```

But like this since its inside the constructor

```
this.prepareToJump
```